# How did they use Fermat's Little Theorem here?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

This is the question:

[image: question.]

In the solution,

[image: solution,]

How did they use FLT to get $6x+6$?

From what I can see here is that in mod7, all the terms between $x^{7}$ and 62 become $0$ in mod7 and the 62 is clearly 6 mod7 but I am not quite sure how the $x^{7}$ is $6x$ mod7.

Comment: Little Fermat theorem says that $x^p\equiv x\pmod p$. Moreover $96x\equiv 5x\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Fermat Little Theorem:  ${x^{p} \equiv x\bmod p}$ , where p is prime, i.e., ${x^p-x} $ is always divisible by p

All term are divisible by 7 except:

$x^7\equiv x \bmod 7$

$96\equiv 5\bmod 7\Rightarrow 96x\equiv 5x\bmod 7$

$62\equiv 6\bmod 7$

So:

$f(x)\equiv (x+5x+6)=(6x+6)\bmod 7$